# Upload file stuck on 'uploading' status with customRequest Ant Design (antd)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I really need your help with uploading files using Ant Design (antd). I don't need request action with upload component, therefore I use the onSuccess() function in customRequest to skip fetch, but onChange method the status stucks only on 'uploading'. It doesn't go to 'done' status. I need your help, please

Sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/runtime-platform-znyow?file=/src/App.js

```
    import React, { useState } from "react";
    import "./styles.css";
    import { Button, Upload } from "antd";

    export default function App() {
      const [fileList, setFileList] = useState([]);

      const fileProps = {
        action: "",
        name: "file",
        multiple: true,
        customRequest(e) {
          e.onSuccess();
        },
        onChange(info) {
          const { status } = info.file;
          console.log(status); // always 'uploading'
          if (status === "done") {
            // this part is unreachable
            let fileList = [...info.fileList];
            setFileList(fileList);
          }
        },
        onRemove: (file) => {
          setFileList((prevState) => prevState.filter((d) => d.uid !== file.uid));
        }
      };

      return (
        <div className="App">
          <Upload {...fileProps} fileList={fileList}>
            <Button type="primary">Attach file</Button>
          </Upload>
        </div>
      );
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

i've had similiar problem after updating version of antd. Here's the code how i fix this without sending request.

```
    const handleChange = useCallback((info) => {
    if (info.file.status === 'uploading') {
        setImage({ loading: true, image: null });
        info.file.status = 'done';
    }
    if (info.file.status === 'done') {
        getBase64(info.file.originFileObj, (imageUrl) => {
            const img = new Image();
            img.src = imageUrl;
            img.addEventListener('load', function () {
                setImage({ loading: false, image: imageUrl });
                setFileList([{ ...info.fileList[0] }]);
            });
        });
    }
}, []);
```

inside condition `(info.file.status === 'uploading')` i've changed `info.file.status === 'done'` and surprsingly it work. Probably there's better solution to solve this, but maybe this will help

Comment: This fix also worked for me. I am wondering if there is a better fix to this.

Comment: For anyone upgrading the antd don't forget to remove your `customRequest={({ onSuccess }) => { onSuccess('ok') }}` that we used in previous versions of antd to cancel actual file uploads, if that method is present this answer won't work

Answer (score 0):

Please setFileList(fileList) in function onChange(info)