# antd Upload customRequest onSuccess() not triggering onChange , while using fileList prop . onchange is stuck on "uploading"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

in below code when I am using fileList prop in with customRequest prop, info.file.status is stuck on "uploading", it never reaches to "done". But when I am using without fileList prop then it's working fine. If there is anybody who can help me with this then it would be a great help.

```
export default function App() {
  const [fileList, setFileList] = useState([]);

  const onUploadChangeHandler = (info) => {
    console.log("onchange", info);
    if (info.file.status === "uploading") {
      console.log("uploading");
    }
    if (info.file.status === "done") {
      console.log("done", info);
      let newArr = [];
      let Location =
        "https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/purple-osteospermum-daisy-flower_1373-16.jpg?w=2000";
      let customFiledata = {
        uid: decodeURI(Location).slice(
          decodeURI(Location).indexOf("uqid") + 5,
          decodeURI(Location).lastIndexOf(".")
        ),
        name: decodeURI(Location).slice(
          decodeURI(Location).indexOf("uqid") + 5
        ),
        status: "done",
        url: Location
      };
      newArr[0] = customFiledata;
      setFileList(newArr);
    } else if (info.file.status === "error") {
      // message.error(`${info.file.name} file upload failed.`);
      console.log("error", info);
    }
  };
  const customRequestHandler = (info) => {
    console.log("customReq", info);
    const { file, onSuccess, onError } = info;
    onSuccess();
  };
  

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Form layout="horizontal" form={form3} onFinish={onFinishHandler}>
        <div className="textarea_row">
          <Form.Item label="Passport Photo" name="passport_photo">
            <div>
              <Upload
                multiple={false}
                className="upload-list-inline"
                customRequest={customRequestHandler}
                fileList={fileList}
                maxCount={1}
                onChange={(info) => {
                  onUploadChangeHandler(info);
                }}
              >
                <Button icon={<UploadOutlined />}>Upload</Button>
              </Upload>
            </div>
          </Form.Item>
        </div>
      </Form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I am expecting to trigger onChange with Success() of customRequest, so that info.file.status==="uploading" change to info.file.status === "done".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Upload file stuck on 'uploading' status with customRequest Ant Design (antd)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66982391/upload-file-stuck-on-uploading-status-with-customrequest-ant-design-antd)